# Java error, Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types; what does this mean?

Tags: java

UPDATED CODE, Error says Illegal static decleration in inner class Mobile.mymobile modifier 'static is only allowed in constant variable declerations, Line 75,  public static void main(String[] args) {  ,what does this mean??

my code:

```
   /**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (jamal) 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private String phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int  memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private String serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private String GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method

    public Mobile(String mobilephonetype, int mobilescreensize,
            int mobilememorycardcapacity,int mobilecameraresolution,String mobileGPS, String newserviceprovider) {
        this.phonetype =  mobilephonetype;
        this.screensize = mobilescreensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = mobilememorycardcapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = mobilecameraresolution;
        this.GPS = mobileGPS;

        // you do not use this ones during instantiation,you can remove them if you do not need or assign them some  default values 
        //this.serviceprovider = newserviceprovider;
        //this.typeofcontract = 12;
        //this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

   Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
    "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
,   1024    // int mobilescreensize 
,   2      // int mobilememorycardcapacity 
,   8       // int mobilecameraresolution 
,   "GPS"    //String mobileGPS
,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider 
);


        //typeofcontract = 12;
        //checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);
         System.out.println("serviceprovider: " + serviceprovider);
        System.out.println("typeofcontract: " + typeofcontract);
}

      /**
 * The mymobile class implements an application that
 * simply displays "new Mobile!" to the standard output.
 */
public class mymobile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("new Mobile!"); //Display the string.
    }
}
    public static void buildPhones(){
    Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 3, 4, 8, "verizon",
                "GPS");
Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", 3, 4,
                8, "verizon", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buildPhones();
}  

}
```

any answers or replies and help would be greatly appreciated as I am totally lost!

Comment: The question is already answered but let me give an advice to you - to prevent such situations don't create methods (constructors) which have more than 4 arguments. Instead of this use [pattern builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or use getters/setters.

Answer (score 1):

> Constructor Mobile Cannot be applied to given types;

Means that you are trying to call a constructor with wrong parameters.

> required:java.lang.String,int,int,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String;

Means that the constructor requires these types for the parameters you pass it

> found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String;

Is what you are actally passing to it.

---

```
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3.0", "4gb", "8mega pixels",
                "GPS");
Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.0", "4gb",
                "8mega pixels", "GPS");
```

You are passing five `String` arguments while your constructor requires one `String`, three `int`s and two `String`s. That's why you get the error.

**UPDATE**

Correct way to do it:

```
Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", 3, 4, 8, "verizon"
                "GPS");
Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", 3, 4,
                8, "verizon", "GPS");
```

Change the parameters to what you want.

Also your first constructor call is wrong.

```
Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
    "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
,   1024    // int mobilescreensize 
,   2      // int mobilememorycardcapacity 
,   8       // int mobilecameraresolution 
,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider 

);
```

A parameter is missing here, it should be

```
Mobile samsungPhone = new Mobile(
    "Samsung" // String mobilephonetype
,   1024    // int mobilescreensize 
,   2      // int mobilememorycardcapacity 
,   8       // int mobilecameraresolution 
,   "GPS"    //String mobileGPS
,   "verizon" // String newserviceprovider 
);
```

Comment: sorry how do i pass one String, three ints and two Strings ??

Comment: @user2898828 See my update. It works but you'll have to change the parameters value according to what you need

Comment: UPDATED CODE, Error says Illegal static decleration in inner class Mobile.mymobile modifier 'static is only allowed in constant variable declerations, Line 75, public static void main(String[] args) { ,what does this mean??

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the 5th argument to the constructor, String mobileGPS.